# Actuator-Enpoint not responding under heavy load on OpenShift

Tags: spring-boot, performance, kubernetes, openshift, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring-Boot (2.7.14) application running on OpenShift 4.13 (Kubernetes version     v1.26.5+7d22122) with activated actuator. I also activated readiness and liveness probes.

If the pod is under heavy CPU load, the liveness probes fail so OpenShift kills the pod and the process is not getting done.

Inside the application we do the number crunching with `.stream().parallel()` calls so we can parallize the process.

I have tried to set some environment variables, but none of them works for me:

- `JAVA_OPTIONS` to `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=2`
- `MANAGEMENT_SERVER_PORT` to `8081`
- `SERVER_TOMCAT_THREADS_MAX` ot `2`
- `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND` to `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=2`

The livenessa and readyness probes look like this:

```yaml
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health/readiness
    port: 8081
    scheme: HTTP
  initialDelaySeconds: 45
  timeoutSeconds: 15
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 3

livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health/liveness
    port: 8081
    scheme: HTTP
  initialDelaySeconds: 45
  timeoutSeconds: 15
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 3
```

I don't want to increase the timeout time in order to notice possible failures at an early stage. The system should at least be responsive to the liveness probes.

Comment: What do the probes do? Do they access shared, limited resources (e.g. a database)?

Comment: No, they are as spring deliveres them. As far as I know, it is just ``OK`` and not the database connection as it might be if I just use ``/acutator/health`` (which is not recommende)

Comment: How many requests is the pod handling when the probe fails? It may be that Tomcat's configuration means that it cannot accept and handle any more requests in which case the probe's failure is an accurate representation of the state of the application.

Comment: I guess two. One request is doing the number crunching and the second is the one handling the health-check. I could reproduce the behaviour on our integration stage to ensure that there is no more load on that pod.

Comment: Those health check probes also consume CPU in a Pod, just like your application does. When the application was under heavy load, it couldn't respond. Could you please provide information about the size of the requests and the CPU limits set for the application?

Comment: limits: cpu: '4', memory: 5Gi; requests: cpu: 200m, memory: 256Mi